# "Removing" even numbers from array and moving odd to the front

Tags: java, arrays

First of all - it's not a homework - I got this question at my last interview and wasn't able to finish it.

So the question was something like: "Given int array k which has length of n, 'remove' all the even numbers and move odd ones to the front". It was worded kinda strange because they said remove but the examples showed that I should just put all odd numbers in front of the array (starting from 0-index) and even numbers can stay in the array (or not - it doesn't matter) after all the odd numbers. 
Example:

```
{1, 4, 6, 8, 7, 2} -> {1, 7, whatever}
{2, 4, 6, 9, 5} -> {9, 5, whatever}
```

I'd like to be as efficient as possible. I couldn't use any additional libraries or temporary arrays.

So far got this but am stuck:

```
private static void removeEven(int[] k, int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (k[i] % 2 == 0) {
    k[i] = // don't know
  }
}
```

Comment: it has to be the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need a counter inside the loop to memorize return array position.
I have used this code, that put to 0 all the remaining array position.

```
private static void removeEven(int[] k, int n) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if (k[i] % 2 == 1)
            k[counter++] = k[i];
    for (int i=counter; i<n; i++)
        k[i] = 0;
}
```

I hope this responses your answer!

Comment: You are putting the even ones in the front!!

Comment: No, I am removing the even and  putting the odd ones in the front. Please, try to execute my code and the result will be the same you requested!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution :

```
 private static int[] removeEven(int[] k, int n) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              if (k[i] % 2 == 0) {
                  for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
                      if(k[j] % 2 != 0){
                          k[i] = k[i] + k[j];
                          k[j] = k[i] - k[j];
                          k[i] = k[i] - k[j];
                          break;//if we get a odd number then we swap it with the even one and so we need not need to proceed the inner loop as the k[i] is already swaped with an oddd number
                      }
                  }
              }
            }
            return k;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reverse the method, what i mean instead of removing the even i would move the odd ones into the front which is what they and they don't care of what is left in the array, so my approach would be like

```
private static int moveOddToFront(int[] k) {
    int frontIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
        boolean isOdd = k[i] % 2 != 0;
        if (isOdd) {
            k[frontIndex] = k[i];
            frontIndex++;
        }
    }

    int newSize = frontIndex;
    return newSize;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this just doesn't work. I tested it with { 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 9, 7,6 } and the result is { 5, 3, 9, 7, 6, 4, 9, 7, 6 }.

Comment: If you look at the original array you will see that you have 4 odd numbers, after the call they are placed in the front of the array and new size would be 4, the question says {odd numbers, whatever}

Comment: I would expect the correct answer to cover all array lengths and not just the one given above. Anyway, it's not really important now.

Comment: I really don't understand what is wrong with this answer, if what bothers you is the rest of the array then you can make them 0 or whatever, the question says that it doesn't care about the rest of the array. please clarify it more

Comment: OK, your solution works if you completely ignore the even elements. I see that some of the solutions don't ignore the even elements.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would just maintain two variables pointing at locations within the array. One would point to the next even number (starting at the beginning), and one would point to the next odd number (starting at the end). While the next even number has a lower index than the next odd, swap them. Here is working and tested code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] test = {2, 4, 6, 9, 5};
    int currentEven = -1;
    int currentOdd = test.length;
    while (currentEven < currentOdd) {
        currentEven = nextEvenIndex(currentEven + 1, test);
        currentOdd = nextLastOddIndex(currentOdd - 1, test);

        if (currentEven < currentOdd) {
            swap(currentOdd, currentEven, test);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(test[i]);
    }
}

private static int nextEvenIndex(int start, int[] array) {
    while (start < array.length) {
        if (array[start] % 2 == 0) {
            return start;
        }
        start++;
    }
    return -1;
}

private static int nextLastOddIndex(int start, int[] array) {
    while (start >= 0) {
        if (array[start] % 2 == 1) {
            return start;
        }
        start--;
    }
    return -1;
}

private static void swap(int index1, int index2, int[] array) {
    int swap = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = swap;
}
```

This is O(n), which is the best performance I think you can get here.

This also performs better than many of the other answers here because a number is never swapped twice; that is, most of these other solutions iterate over the whole array (sometimes making unnecessary swaps) while this iterates over only half.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following pseudo-code that will return the array with odds first, evens last, and will retain original order of the odd and even subsets.

```
if array.length < 2 
  return array
else
  p=0
  while array[p].odd and p < array.length
    p++
  q = p+1
  if q < array.length
    repeat
      if array[q].odd
        swap(array,p,q) p++ q++
      else
        q++
    until q >= array.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable where you put the value to move, than use another variable to set the place where you will put the value to move.

Code :

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (k[i] % 2 != 0 ) {
            int tempInt = k[j];
            k[j] = k[i];
            k[i] = tempInt;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using below code we can remove all even from array and write the rest array.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        int a[]={7,9,7,8,4};

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            boolean x=false;
            if(a[i]%2==0){
                x=true;
            }
            if(!x){
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple python solution for the same,

```
def moveEven(arr):
    start, end = 0, len(arr)-1
    while start <= end:
        if arr[start] % 2 == 0:
            arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]
            end -= 1
        else:
            start += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution puts all the odd numbers in the front of the array and zeros for the rest of the positions.

Test cases:

```java
int[] array1 = { 1, 4, 6, 8, 7, 2 };
int[] array2 = { 2, 4, 6, 9, 5 };

reverse(array1,6);  // result: [1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0]
reverse(array2,5);  // result: [9, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Code:

```java
public static void reverse(int[] array, int N) {
    if (N < 2) {
        return;
    }
    int index = 0;  // index at which the next odd number should be placed
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 1) {
            array[index] = array[i];
            if (i > index) {
                array[i] = 0;
            }
            index++;
        } else {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```